# CFHttp Retrycount wait

Tags: coldfusion

How does the `retrycount` attribute work in CFHttp? I want to know how long it waits to retry again when a process failure is reported?

Does it depend on the `timeout` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear if that the attribute `retrycount` is supported by `<cfhttp>`. I did a search and only found it mentioned [here](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/6.1/htmldocs/tags-p41.htm) for an older version of CF. But even there it's just mentioned in passing rather than as part of the actual specification.

Also in CFBuilder `retrycount` is not part of the `cfhttp` autocomplete option - which also makes me suspicious.

Perhaps you can let us know the version of CF you are using - but my investigations seem to suggest it's either not supported or deprecated.

**UPDATE:**

It's not supported. Just tried to use that attribute on CF 9, and got an error:

*Attribute validation error for the http tag.*

*The tag does not have an attribute called retrycount. The valid attribute(s) are url, port, method, username, password, name, columns, charset, path, file, delimiter, textqualifier, resolveurl, proxyserver, proxyport, proxyUser, proxyPassword, useragent, throwonerror, redirect, firstRowAsHeaders, timeout, multipart, multipartType, getAsBinary, result, clientCert, clientCertPassword, compression.*

One way around this to guarantee at least one retry is to include the `throwonerror` attribute and then catch the error. There you can choose to retry the connection one more time. That or some variation on it might sort you out even if it's not very elegant. Hope this helps anyway.

Comment: Garrr...!! so.. it's useless now..!!